# The distribution of bias of MLE and the asymptotic distribution of $n(\widehat{\beta}_n - \beta)$

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics

$Y_i = \beta X_i + \epsilon_i$, $i=1,...,n$, where $X_i>0$ for all $i$, and $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2,...,\epsilon_n$ are iid exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$. $\widehat{\beta}_n$ is the MLE of $\beta$.

How can I get the distribution of $\widehat{\beta}_n - \beta$ and the asymptotic distribution of $n(\widehat{\beta}_n - \beta)$ ?

It's easy to deal with the asymptotic of $\sqrt{n}(\widehat{\beta}_n - \beta)$ based on the properties of MLE. I feel it difficult in dealing with the bias and the asymptotic of $n(\widehat{\beta}_n - \beta)$.

Comment: What do you get for $\hat\beta_n$?

Comment: To make your life simpler, try working it out for the special case of $X_i = 1 \,\forall\, i$.  You can see it's a noncentral exponential distribution with noncentrality parameter $\beta$; at that point, deriving the MLE and distribution thereof should be straightforward using properties of the exponential distribution.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/453450/119261